# How can I create a new table of tables with modified values from another table

Tags: lua

how could I make a new table like

```
local beesNumbers = {
[1]={[1]={1,2}},
[2]={1,2},
[3]={[1]={[1]={1,2}}},
[4]={1,2,3},
}
```

but with all the numbers divided by 8

so basically the same format but every number value is devided by 8

Comment: When you say `all numbers divide by 8` does that include the keys?

Comment: any own attempt? share your thoughts/code.